# Calling images in another directory

Tags: javascript, image, subdirectory

I'm really not sure what the fancy jargon for this stuff is so Im sorry if I dont use the right terminology.

Im working with a script where the images are located in a subdirectory than where the html is located.

This is the snippet of code:

```
eval("document.hm.src=\"hm" + wrong_guesses + ".gif\"");
```

In the world of html the image path would normally look like: games/word/hm01.gif

How do I modify that line of javascript to reflect that the images are in the subdirectory? I'm lost and I'm sure it's something simple but I'm not a programmer, I just lightly tweak stuff :\

Comment: What do you mean to reflect the images in a subdirectory? Whay does `wrong_guesses` look like?

Comment: This is a script for a game where you guess letters a few times.

Wrong Guesses are the number sequence so they would call on hm01.gif, hm02.gif etc etc up to 10 depending on how many times you got the question wrong. 

The problem is..as this script is written it believes the images are in the same folder as the html it's embedded in. The images are actually in a subdirectory. 

How do I get this string to call on them?

Comment: That would be something like `eval("document.hm.src=\"games/word/hm" + wrong_guesses + ".gif\"");`.

Comment: It worked! You got it!!!! :D You're the best! I knew it was something simple and I was just overlooking the quotes..God this was killing me. Thank you!!! ^_^ Now I can go sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be : `eval("document.hm.src=\"games/word/hm" + wrong_guesses + ".gif\"");`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
eval("document.hm.src='\hm\'+img_name+'.gif'");
```